# Showing error while using JWT library version 8.5.1 with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, jwt

I am trying to using JWT token to add authentication on my react app. But, it's showing me this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\HETARTH RAVAL\Desktop\WebDev\20-quotes\client\node_modules\jwa'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\HETARTH RAVAL\Desktop\WebDev\20-quotes\client\node_modules\jwa'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

I got exactly same error for 'util' and 'stream'. I tried looking for some fix on jwt repo on github. It says this error appears after updating react scripts to ^5.0.0. I dont exactly know how to fix this. How do I make these errors go away?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`

as the suggestion suggests on line no. 305 you need changes like this.

```
resolve: { fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")}
```

[image]

This tells webpack to use the crypto-browserify package as a fallback when the crypto module is not found.
You also need to install the crypto-browserify package in your project by running this command in your terminal:

```
> npm install crypto-browserify
```

**NB: If you didnt find the line resolve on the line 305 in webpack.config.js use the search option**